# How to grep some particular word out of multiple text files

Tags: regex, shell

I have multiple text files (let say a.txt) whose contents is as shown below. I need to grep ICV tool version  (in this case it is ICV:2018.12-1) out of this files. Can any body help me to grep tool version after ICV as this tool version (2018.12-1) is changing from one text file to another text file but this format is remains same for all files like `;tool name:tool version;tool name:tool version;`?

1) a.txt

```
setenv VDK_TOOL_VERS 'CDESIGNER:2014.12-SP2-2;CUSTOMCOMPILER:2018.09-SP1-1;HSPICE:2018.09-SP1-1;XA:2018.09-SP2;STARRCXT:2018.06-SP5;ICV:2018.12-1;PYLCC:2008.09-SP4-11;CALIBRE:2018.2-15.10;CIRANOVA:2012.12-1-gcc44x;HERCULES:2008.09-SP5-2;WAVEVIEW:2019.06';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for what is not a semicolon:

```
$ grep -o 'ICV:[^;]*' a.txt
ICV:2018.12-1
```

Only the version using lookbehinds:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=ICV:)[^;]*' a.txt
2018.12-1
```

[Lookahead & Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the how does it work?